# How to get Target name?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, build-process

We know that Xcode maintains environment variable of `${TARGET_NAME}` but how to access this variable in objective-C code ?

What I have tried ?
I have added `"TARGET_NAME=${TARGET_NAME}"` this in Preprocessor macros section of Build Settings. But now I am not sure how to use this variable `"TARGET_NAME"` as a string in objective-C code.

In my case product name and target name are different so, no chance to use that.

I tried to access using

```
#ifdef TARGET_NAME
 NSLog(@"TargetIdentifier %@",TARGET_NAME);
#endif
```

This code is giving error like "Use of undeclared identifier 'myapptargetname'"

Comment: Try to use this link.Might be helpful.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14271710/programmatically-determine-current-target-run-or-test-in-ios-project

Comment: Thanks but I already tried this so,I have edited my question. That works if your environment variable is integer.

Comment: Ok dear and congtrs....

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You can add "TargetName" key to your Info.plist file:

[image]

Then you can access it (swift code):

```
var plistFileName = NSBundle.mainBundle().infoDictionary?["TargetName"] as String
```

Comment: I had already achieved solution but didn't get time to updated here. Thanks for posting solution so, other can get help

Comment: How do we access it on Objective C? And where should I type this code out? @Iducool I've spent so much time on finding this target name and I still cant find it :(

Comment: @WendyMunmunWang NSString *plistFileName = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"TargetName"];

Comment: @VasilValchev It works on xcode 7 as well. Please note that this key is not presented in Info.plist by default, you have to add it manually by yourself.

Comment: Not working now, must be updated to `let plistFileName = Bundle.main.infoDictionary?["TargetName"] as? String ?? ""`

Answer (score 30):

```
NSLog(@"Target name: %@",[[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleName"]);
```

Hope to help you!

**Edited: "CFBundleName"** 
thanks Max and Daniel Bo for your commend

Comment: I have already tried this. It is giving Product name. And value of this key is depend upon the info.plist

Comment: it is better to use "CFBundleName"

Comment: CFBundleName works like a charm +1, CFBundleDisplayName returns null

Comment: Is there any chances of app rejection, if I use this way to get the target name?

Comment: Absolutely not! Apple will reject your application with some common reject listed in the following link: https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/rejections/

Comment: Not `CFBundleName`, nor `CFBundleDisplayName` return target name, most likely they will be set in Info.plist to return product name.

Answer (score 22):

**Swift 4, Xcode 9+**

Bundle name:

```
Bundle.main.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: "CFBundleName") as? String ?? ""
```

Bundle display name:

```
Bundle.main.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: "CFBundleDisplayName") as? String ?? ""
```

**Swift 3, Xcode 8+**

```
let targetName = Bundle.main.infoDictionary?["CFBundleName"] as? String ?? ""
```

Comment: doesnt print target name, it prints the display name :)

Comment: Not `CFBundleName`, nor `CFBundleDisplayName` return target name, most likely they will be set in Info.plist to return product name.

Answer (score 4):

**Swift 5:**

```
var plistFileName = Bundle.main.infoDictionary?["CFBundleName"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I must credit [the original answer by vk.edward.li](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8888947/7395227), as this answer only merely expands on it.

All the build setting macros can easily be used in source code as preprocessor macros too. The problem is that they're not set in advance; you have to specify which ones you get access to, yourself.

[image]

I've already added three extra preprocessor macros. Simply click the `+`, and add this: `TARGET_NAME=\""$TARGET_NAME"\"`, and you've granted yourself access to one more build setting macro.

`Project settings ––> Build Settings ––> Apple Clang - Preprocessing[Preprocessor Macros]`. Note that if you try to insert them for both compilation modes at once, the `DEBUG=1` macro will get deleted, but it can as easily be added right back afterwards.

It's also worth noting that the macro values should be set differently for different languages: `Objective-C` and `C++`/`Swift`, etc. This is due to the `NSString` prefix used in `Objective-C`, so for that language, it should be `MACRO=@\""$MACRO"\"` instead of `MACRO=\""$MACRO"\"`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have lots of targets this method will be move convenient than the one suggested by @Sergey Demchenko, as you'll do it once and there will be no need to do any changes in Info.plist if you add new target.

1. Go to Project Build Settings (not Target's Build Settings), and add the following Preprocessor Macro(s):

```
TARGET_NAME="$(TARGET_NAME)"
```

[image]

2. Now, we need to get value of this macro in our code. Swift doesn't support string macros, so we'll need to go back to good old Objective-C.

Add the following files:

`AppTargetName.h`:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

NSString * _Nullable AppTargetName(void);
```

`AppTargetName.m`, with some C preprocessor magic (thanks [to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7605905/299063)):

```
#import "AppTargetName.h"

#ifndef TARGET_NAME
    #define TARGET_NAME ""
#endif

#define STRINGIZE(x) #x
#define STRINGIZE2(x) STRINGIZE(x)
#define TARGET_NAME_STRING @ STRINGIZE2(TARGET_NAME)

NSString * _Nullable AppTargetName() {
    if (TARGET_NAME_STRING.length == 0) {
        return nil;
    } else {
        return TARGET_NAME_STRING;
    }
}
```

3. Add `#import "AppTargetName.h"` to Obj-c Bridging header (and add/configure it if you don't have one).
4. And now in Swift, you may call `AppTargetName()` and get your target name, without need to modify Info.plist if you add new target!

```
if let targetName = AppTargetName() {
    print("Target Name = \(targetName)")
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In Xcode 7.3.1

```
if let targetName = NSBundle.mainBundle().infoDictionary?["CFBundleName"] as? String{
    print(targetName)
}
```

Comment: This prints the bundle name

Comment: Not `CFBundleName`, nor `CFBundleDisplayName` return target name, most likely they will be set in Info.plist to return product name.