# Write an if condition for specific target in the app

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm trying to write an if condition in appdelegate method, There are two targets in my app. The if condition should work only for one target.

```
#if TEST
    var startUrl: String = "http://www.example.com"
#elseif TEST_2
    var startUrl: String = "http://www.example2.com"
#endif
```

TEST and TEST_2 are two targets, and URL will be selected according to the selected target. This is the start url of my app. There is a function after this. I need that function to be executed only if TEST target is running. What do I do?

Comment: Each target has its own Build Settings where you can defined any custom symbols. Did you try that?

Comment: See also: [How get get Target Name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18783055/how-to-get-target-name)

Comment: Actually there is a function in appdelegate.swift file. That needs to be executed. I only need to add an if condition on top of that function

Answer (score 5):

Testing your target name is not good. Especially if this code goes to production.

Let's assume:

**TEST** is a target pointing your **Stagging Env** (*integration*)
And **TEST_2** is a target pointing your **Production Env**.

A better approch would be :

- Open the Preview's target's build settings
- Create a Preprocessor Macro like **STAGGING=1** for your target TEST

Then, all you have to do is:

```
#if STAGGING
    var startUrl: String = "http://www.example.com"
#els
    var startUrl: String = "http://www.example2.com"
#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get target name like this :

```
let targetName = Bundle.main.infoDictionary?["CFBundleName"] as! String
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create two small source files with a different "constant" declaration in each one.  Then include the appropriate source file only in the target it pertains to.

for example

```
 // file: example1.swift (only included in target 1)
 let targetStartURL = "http://www.example1.com"
```

...

```
 // file: example2.swift (only included in target 2)
 let targetStartURL = "http://www.example2.com"
```

The you won't even need an if statement in your delegate. You simply use the global variable in the initialization:

```
 var startURL = targetStartURL
```