# Do different things on different Targets

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm working on a very complex app that has several different versions of it.

Inside that App I need a way to detect the current target and do stuff when the right target is detected.

For example we have Targets A, B, C, D. I'd need to do something like this

If target = A { 
do something
{ else if target = B {
do something else 
{ else if target = C ....

Comment: Do you mean the target of `-[UIControl addTarget:action:forControlEvents:]` or some other sort of target?

Comment: Check out this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18783055/how-to-get-target-name .